# crossOriginIsolated is false at not localhost address. How can I fix it?

Tags: firefox, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I want to use SharedArrayBuffer on Firefox.
So I let my web server add Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy in response header according to [the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer).

It works fine when you access the server as localhost, but it does not work when you access the server as its IP address.
How can I fix it?

The version of Firefox is 83.0.

Thanks.

Comment: I see this question is a few months old now. I have received an email from Google Search Console telling me `Google systems have recently detected that SharedArrayBuffers (SABs) are used on` my site. However, I have no idea what they are, or how to detect where I am using them on my site. As you mention wanting to use them, would you mind providing any info about what they are please? I have read the Mozilla page about them, but still have no idea how I can be using them on my site, which uses some CDNs and displays some videos using iFrames. Any advice much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @4532066 san, SABs are mainly used for communications among main thread and web workers. If you use multithread C/C++ program via Emscripten on your site, it may use SABs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need HTTPS when not accessing the server by localhost.

It is explained in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer/Planned_changes) by the following line :

> As a baseline requirement, documents will need to be in a secure
> context.