# Does Firefox for Android 82 support SharedArrayBuffer?

Tags: android, firefox, sharedarraybuffer

Related with [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64904041/crossoriginisolated-is-false-at-not-localhost-address-how-can-i-fix-it), next I tried to use SharedArrayBuffer on Firefox for Android 82.

I failed it via both localhost and https server.

Hasn't Firefox for Android 82 supported SharedArrayBuffer yet?

[The document](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) says that Firefox for Android supports it since version 79.
Then how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [linked MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) is in Japanese and stale. If you look at [the English version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer), you'll learn that it needs "cross-origin isolation" to enable `SharedArrayBuffer`.

Cross-origin isolation is very constrained environment, but if you are interested to learn more you may start from here: https://web.dev/coop-coep/

Comment: san, Thank you for your comment!. I had tried it as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64904041/crossoriginisolated-is-false-at-not-localhost-address-how-can-i-fix-it. Now I believe that Android Firefox has a certain issue. And I confirmed Android Chrome 90(beta) works well.